# Troubleshooting a UNC path

Tags: networking, ms-access-2016

I reference full UNC paths in my database linked tables to prevent ambiguity.  Suddenly with this same reference in the linked tables one user - Kris is able to access the paths with no problems but 
all users see a different end folder and when Kris writes to the folder, no one can see her files.  Nothing changed apparently except for (guessing) the user’s permissions? How can I go about troubleshooting this.

For Example:

This is the path all users have to get to "FinalLocation"

```
\\Server\divHQ\AA\FinalLocation
```

She has a mapping of "O" to

```
\\Server\divHQ\AA
```

So this is a valid path for her

O:\FinalLocation

But if she manually types in the address

```
\\Server\divHQ\AA\FinalLocation
```

It should stay that way.  But it doesn't.

It converts to

```
O:\FinalLocation
```

Finally, the access database does NOT use the "O" mapping, it uses the complete

```
\\Server\divHQ\AA\FinalLocation
```

If Kris uploads anything to any folder in FinalLocation including overwriting files in that location, none of the users see her changes!

She appears to be in her own isolated world.

Comment: Are you using IP addresses or hostnames in the UNC path?

Comment: Hostnames. This is why it is so peculiar. How can two people have the same path but end up with different destinations unless it is security permissions to view a document created by a particular user.

Comment: Ping the server name from each machine involved. Ensure that the name is resolving to the same IP address on each machine.

Comment: Their cmd prompt is disabled. The only thing we can determine is that Kris is different from three other users.